# Find and replace SSH command across multiple files?

Tags: ssh, command

So this command will replace abc with XYZ in file.txt in directory tmp

> sed -ie 's/abc/XYZ/g' /tmp/file.txt

How do you do a find and replace like this across a large number of files in a directory with a .html extension in one go?

Comment: `man SO rules`? This is offtopic here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
find /start/path -name *.html -exec sed -ie 's/abc/XYZ/g' '{}' \;
```

As by your request, here is what it does:

```
find /start/path -name *.html
```

Finds all files that glob to *.html, starting in /start/path

The -exec option tells find, to not just print out the files, but to run a command on them. Inside this command {} is replaced by the file. The -exec option hast to end with a semicolon, which we have to escape with a backslash, else bash will swallow it.

Again, from the OP's special situation: Put the following into a file called replaceabc.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
find '/home/129224/domains/sandpit.uk-cpi.com/html/sshit' -name '*.html' -exec sed -ie 's/abc/XYZ/g' '{}' \;
```

then from the shell prompt

```
chmod 700 /path/to/replaceabc.sh
/path/to/replaceabc.sh
```

Comment: That seems to have worked! But Why??

Comment: OK, when you log into a Linux command line, you are inside some "shell", which is similar to Windows' cmd.exe, that accepts and executes your commands. Different Shells follow different semantics, especially with quoting. Now by putting the commands into a shellscript (similar to a batch file in Windows) and prefixing it with #!/bin/bash I can force that file to be interpreted by the "bash" shell, which is why it worked. In short: I moved the parsing of the command line from the unknown shell you get via SSH to the known bash.

Comment: I need to sub /abc/ for /define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', 3);/. I know I need to escape the single quotes, but that wasn't enough, I still got a `bash: syntax error near unexpected token \`)'`. What's the proper escaping for this?

Comment: Added http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965993/escaping-regex-in-sed if you want to earn some points :)

Comment: I tried the command above and it didn't go through, some syntax error (message: `find: paths must precede expression: conf`). I don't have the time to investigate it, but I worked around it executing this command:
`find my_folder/ -type f -exec sed -i 's/string_to_find/string_to_replace_with/g' {} \;`. Worked beautifully.

Comment: You might need to quote the glob pattern, such as `find /start/path -name '*.html'`...